# Orbeon Form Builder - Sending PDF to Java REST web service

Tags: rest, orbeon

I want to send a PDF with the user entered data once the send button of Orbeon Form Builder is clicked, I have created a rest service for this and I have come up to this stage by referring the [documentation](http://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/advanced/buttons-and-processes/actions-form-runner.html#sending-a-pdf-url). Now I get the below output to my java rest service:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<url>/xforms-server/dynamic/5325aebace78df08fbc408ebdfaa818f7262d6b2</url>
```

How can I proceed after this to retrieve the PDF file and save in my file server? How do I generate and use this session cookie? Any coding sample would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have sample code to share for this, but in essence:

- You need to do an HTTP GET to the provided URL on the server running Orbeon Forms.
- You're most likely doing this in code servicing the HTTP request made by Orbeon Forms that sent you that document with the URL. There, read the session cookie (typically the `JSESSIONID` cookie), you received in that query, and send that cookie in the HTTP GET request you're making.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for replying... Can I please know whether `JSESSIONID` is the 5325aebace78df08fbc408ebdfaa818f7262d6b2 that I got from `<url>/xforms-server/dynamic/5325aebace78df08fbc408ebdfaa818f7262d6b2</url>`

Comment: No, the JSESSIONID is a Cookie, so you'll find it in the HTTP request headers. E.g. you would have a header that looks like: `Cookie: JSESSIONID=9635321C48CE1657629742542B319A0A; __uvt=; __qca=P0-1024895509-1454346175963; uvts=1mBLM41D49CEkLXv`. The JSESSIONID is tied to the user's session, and picked by Tomcat.